# How to link an onclick event to a javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to link the following onclick function

```html
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
Nombre o RUT:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value=" ">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

myLink.onclick = function(){

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://rutificadorcom.s3.amazonaws.com/CACHE/js/fdb8313f6402.js"; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    return false;

}


</script>


</body>
```

To the js code published here: https://rutificadorcom.s3.amazonaws.com/CACHE/js/fdb8313f6402.js

But I don't know why after clicking the button My search does not yield any results.

I have already copied and pasted the js code in a local file on my computer to refer to it in my own machine. However, this action has not worked either.

Comment: you have no function called `myFunction` and you have no element with id `mylink` - so of course nothing happens

Comment: I want to know what it means to link something "to a javascript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "make a button do something when you click it" in your code just name the function you want to do as 'myFunction' (same name you putted on the onclick).

**Your code fixed:**

```
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
Nombre o RUT:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value=" ">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
  alert("Hi!");
}

</script>

</body>
```

That works but, it would be better if you do this on a external js file and without the onclick.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="alertButton">Click me</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var buttonWithAlert = document.querySelector('#alertButton');

buttonWithAlert.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Hi!");
});
```